# NLog control to an existing RichTextBox Windows Form

Tags: c#, nlog

Below is my NLog configuration, I want to load log into existing RichTextBox called rtMessage in Form1, but NLog will create a new windows with log message loaded into the RichTextBox:

```
 <targets>
    <target xsi:type="RichTextBox" name="m" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" 
            controlName="rtMessage" formName="Form1" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="m" />
  </rules>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Exception at Program.cs The type initializer for Form1.Form1' threw an exception.

Comment: @KelvinFixx There is an [old issue](http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/4483) reported at the NLog Codeplex site regarding exception in type initializer for the `RichTextBox` target. The issue appears to have been solved in 2.0. Are you using a recent version of NLog?

Comment: If I understand the [NLog documentation](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/RichTextBox_target) correctly you should be able to link `formName` to an existing `Form` in your application. Have you tried this? BTW, is your application WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: I have solved the problem, changing form to formName. Now the problem is it create it's own form.

Comment: And it will not work to set `formName` and `controlName` to a form and control already existing in your application? Anyway, to help other readers, it would be really good if you could write up (and accept) your own answer, i.e. that `form` should be `formName`. Alternatively, rephrase the question to emphasize that you would like to attach the NLog control to an existing `Form`.

Comment: windows form, my form name is Form1.

Comment: According to the documentation the form has to be open before you attach the NLog target. Perhaps you need to create your target programmatically, as I assume the NLog configuration is executed before UI component initialization?

Comment: You might be right, then it defect the purpose of having config file.

Comment: @Andres Gustafsson Yeh you are right! http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/2707

Comment: @KelvinFixx I found it too. I was just giving the answer a final touch when I saw your comment :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can find the answer to your issue on the NLog Codeplex forum, [here](http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/2707).

If you initialize the `static` `logger` directly in the field declaration inside your `Form1` form, the `Form1` *instance* will not yet exist, and NLog will go on creating a new form for the `RichTextBox` target.

What you need to do is delay the initialization of the `logger` to a time when the `Form1` instance is already initialized, for example in a `Load` event handler.

Here is an excerpt of functional code from the Codeplex issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static Logger logger;// = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }
}
```

To avoid unnecessary re-initialization, you might want to initialize `logger` only if it has not already been initialized, i.e.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (logger == null) logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.normally init logger in `winform1_Load` 
while it have done `InitializeComponent` -> has init your own RichTextBox.

2.then makesure your `RichTextBoxTarget`'s `FormName` and `ControlName` initialized ok.
such as:

```
RichTextBoxTarget rtbTarget = new RichTextBoxTarget();
logConfig.AddTarget("richTextBox", rtbTarget);
rtbTarget.FormName = "frmScrapeAmazonProduct"; // your winform class name
rtbTarget.ControlName = "rtbLog"; // your RichTextBox control/variable name
```

more can refer [my post](http://www.crifan.com/csharp_nlog_richtextbox_alwayls_create_new_window/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are three tips to help you load log in existing RichTextBox.

1. Ensure formName and controlName is consistent with the actual use
2. Set `allowAccessoryFormCreation="False"` in NLog.config
3. `RichTextBoxTarget.ReInitializeAllTextboxes(this);` in Form_Load

PS:Follow this way, you neeed to config your RichTextBoxTarget in NLog.config, please refer [RictTextBoxTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Windows.Forms/wiki/RichTextBoxTargetq).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add

```
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

if setting the richtextbox as a logger programmatically

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Windows.Forms/wiki/RichTextBoxTarget

I have the similar problems to nlog into the windows.form. I used the NLog.Windows.Forms
 from the Nugget with the Nlog, and Nlog.config.
I follow that given templatefrom the link and make it work without any manual initialisation. I provide part of the code into the Nlog.config. Hope it helps.

```
<targets>
<target xsi:type="RichTextBox"
      name="richTextBox1"
      layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
      height="30"
      autoScroll="true"
      maxLines="60"
      showMinimized="true"
      toolWindow="true"
      controlName="richTextBox1"
      formName="Form1"
      width="50"
      useDefaultRowColoringRules="true"
      allowAccessoryFormCreation="true"
      messageRetention="None"
      supportLinks="false"
>
</target>
</targets>
```