# How to embed Nlog richtexbox in window form?

Tags: logging, nlog, error-logging

I am using Nlog for managing logging in my application.I am having a Form which does sometask and a richtextbox is there where I want to show the Log details.Configuration of Nlog.config file is:

```
   <target name="name" formName="FormName" controlName="RichTextBoxName" xsi:type="RichTextBox" layout="${date} | ${message}" ></target> //this is target tag

 <logger name="*"  level ="Info" writeTo="name"></logger> //this logger tag
```

The thing is that when I am running the application I am getting two forms :

**The form which I created ** and

**another form which displays the log **

I want to **embed the Log form to richtextbox of my form(formname)** or want to bind the data of the log form to the richextbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some info from here on SO about some issues people have had using the RichTextBoxTarget and how to work around them:

[NLog control to an existing RichTextBox Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631959/nlog-control-to-an-existing-richtextbox-windows-form)

The second link describes the issue that you describe (the second form being displayed) and how to work around it.