# NLog RichTextBox config issue

Tags: nlog

I have C# (.NET 3.5) Winforms app, where I use NLog. I want to use RichTextBox target but getting error.

```
<targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/AppLog.txt" />
        <target xsi:type="RichTextBox"
          name="rtbLog1"
          layout="${message}"
          height="800"
          autoScroll="true"
          maxLines="0"
          showMinimized="false"
          toolWindow="false"
          controlName="rtb2"
          formName="frmConverter"
          width="800"
          useDefaultRowColoringRules="false">
            <word-coloring backgroundColor="Blue" fontColor="Red" ignoreCase="true"
                        regex="Error" style="Regular" text="Error"
                        wholeWords="true"/>
             <!--repeated--> 
            <row-coloring backgroundColor="Blue" condition="Condition" fontColor="Red"
                       style="Regular"/>
             <!--repeated--> 
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="rtbLog1" />
    </rules>
```

The error thrown is:
The type initializer for 'app.program' threw an exception.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I just updated condition="level == LogLevel.Debug" in config file and the app started without issue. However, the log is written to a new form and not using the richtextbox in existing form. Is this by design?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631959/nlog-control-to-an-existing-richtextbox-windows-form) seems similar to your situation. This was probably due to the form not existing when the nlog config was loaded. Setting up the logger programmatically after InitializeComponent() is called seems like the safest way to avoid this problem.

Comment: OK Thanks for your reply.. will check